# searching process memory

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++, memory-leaks

I'm working on a C++/MFC program that's leaking memory.  The memory allocation numbers are different on each run, so using `_CrtSetBreakAlloc()` won't help me locate the allocation.

The memory is definitely a `CString`:

> f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(141) : {28660}
>   normal block at 0x02353F98, 29 bytes long.  Data: << N†X            >
>   3C 4E 86 58 0C 00 00 00 0C 00 00 00 01 00 00 00

And the string mostly starts with the following sequence:

> < N†X

I would d like to know if there's a way to search process memory (while execution is paused in debug mode) so I can search for this string, and possibly determine the allocation point in the code, or even the variable name?

Answer (score 0):

Better use [Visual Leak Detector](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/visualleakdetector.aspx)

Comment: As it turned out, adding Visual Leak Detector actually hid the memory leaks!  So I'm sticking with _CrtDumpLeaks and friends.  GlowCode seems to be the most helpful app I've found, but it doesn't really answer my initial question.